# setting state to an array using hooks, react

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I've tried different solutions to similar problems provided here and none of them worked, whenever i try to add to an array or set a state to a new array using hooks, i always get an error caused by too many re renders. no matter if i wrap my logic in arrow functions, or try adding to `prevState`, no matter if i use `concat`, `push`, `map`, `filter` always the same result. So i thought to create my array first, before even declaring the state variable, like that:

```
const newCompletedItems = data.map(obj => obj.completed ? obj.id : null).filter(item => item);
const [completedItems, setCompletedItems] = useState(newCompletedItems);
```

No error messages there, but i get an array with 0 items, while `newCompletedItems` is an array with multiple items (as expected).

Basically i need to set the state to an array that is an outcome of a function and then in future i'll need to `setCompletedItems` again, by adding to/ substracting from `completedItems` array.

Comment: Pretty sure this isn’t the code that’s causing a rendering recursion. Are you any point updating completedItems with a useEffect that has itself as a dependency, or any logic of a similar nature that will lead to recursion?

Comment: no , this code is not causing recursion, there were 5 -10 different attempts that did, so i changed my approach, I created the array and then tried to set the state to that array, didn't get any errors this time, but instead got an array with 0 items, while the array that i'm passing to the state **has multiple itmes**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what finally worked for me, was to use `useEffect` as advised, but instead of passing empty dependency array as a second argument, i passed in the actual array that i'm trying to set the state to.

Here's the code with two of these `useEffect`s (variable names changed since original post):

```
const [toDosData, setToDosData] = useState([]);
const [completedItems, setCompletedItems] = useState([]);     

useEffect(() => {
    data && setToDosData(data);
}, [data]);

useEffect(() => {
    toDosData.length && setCompletedItems(toDosData.filter(data => data.completed))
}, [toDosData])
```

So basically when i was passing empty dependency array i was getting results after first render, for some reason the expected result comes only after 2nd render.

Answer (score 1):

The lack of code examples makes it quite difficult to spot the problem (because we don't know what else is going on in your component)

But here is an educated guess to what was the cause of some of your problems (especially the rerender ones):

In Javascript arrays are passed by reference not value.

so let's say you have a component as follows:

```
function Component (data) {
  const [array, setArray] = useState()
  setArray(data.map(x => x))

  return (<div></div>)
}
```

let's see what happens on the inital-render of this Component.

`array` and `setArray` get initialized by the useState hook. Then we use `setArray()` to change our state to `data.map(x => x)` - let's call this array DataArray1. State change causes a rerender, so let's do a rerender.

1st rerender of the Component:

the state variable `array` will be set to what it latest value was - so in our case since we just set `array` to `dataArray1`, our state is now  = DataArray1. Then we use `setArray()` to change our state. React will compare the current state to the new state and only rerender if they are not the same. But since arrays are passed by reference the comparison `dataArray1 === data.map(x => x)` returns false. So React is like: "ok those values are different so let's change the state to this new (completely different) value. And since our state changed let's do a rerender.

so here we go again; 2nd rerender:

and since I am not really in the mood to type out an infinite recursive function we will stop here.

You can solve that problem by wrapping it all in an `useEffect()` hook with empty dependency array - so that it will only get called on initial render. Or just pass the array to the `useState` hook as initial value like so: `useState(data.map(x => x))`

The important thing to remember is: ARRAYS ARE PASSED BY REFFERENCE!!! (all objects are for that matter)

A basic tip: In components everything should be in hooks (most of the time)

Comment: thanks for the explanation of why do i get re render, it's very useful, but if  i wrap the code inside `useEffect` i still get an empty array, just like when i set the state directly with `setCompleted` (despite the fact that the array i'm setting the state to is not empty. Its interesting though, because if i change the code slightly, for example from `map` to `filter` or vice versa, **while** hosting the project in local server, **then** the correct array is being logged to the console.

Comment: and if i use `const arr = data.map(obj => obj.completed ? obj.id : null);

    useEffect(() => { 
        setCompletedItems(completedItems => [...completedItems, arr]);
    }, []);` then i get an array of 2 elements, each element being empty array.